# How to add images and anchor tag into infowindow using google plugin for cordova?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-markers, cordova-plugins

> How to add images and anchor tag into infowindow using google plugin
>   for cordova?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using this plugin cordova-plugin-googlemaps.

If yes then

`var html = "<img src='./House-icon.png' width='64' height='64' >" +
           "<br>" +
           "This is an example";
htmlInfoWindow.setContent(html);
htmlInfoWindow.open(marker);`

Taken from this source https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps